# Unsolved problems in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question

Is there a good database of unsolved problems in graph theory?

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia has a listing of [open problems in graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics#Graph_theory).

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few that I know of (with overlap of course).

It's unclear how up-to-date they are.

Douglas West's page: http://www.math.illinois.edu/~dwest/openp/

The Open Problem Garden: http://www.openproblemgarden.org/category/graph_theory

Erdos' Problems on Graphs: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~erdosproblems/